# Why do toothpicks in Italy have Japanese brand names?

Tags: foreign-words, foreign-influence

I've just come back from a visit to Romagna. It was my second time in Italy and the first time was a very long time ago.

I noticed that Italian toothpicks all seem to have Japanese brand names: Samurai, Kimono, Karate.

Does this indicate a cultural perspective on toothpicks, or is it (as I suspect) just unthinking me-too imitation of a leading brand?

Comment: According to this page http://www.lindaliguori.it/samurai-lo-stuzzicadenti/ the name "Samurai" was chosen in 1965 by the manifacturers after their meeting with a japanese exporter of timber.
I am not sure, but I think that the other names just tried to follow its wave of success.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Thank you. Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this page: http://www.lindaliguori.it/samurai-lo-stuzzicadenti/ the name "Samurai" was chosen in 1965 by the manifacturers after their meeting with a japanese exporter of timber. I am not sure, but I think that the other names just tried to follow its wave of success, so your guess about the "*imitation of a leading brand*" seems IMO correct.